# How to create a dynamic calendar in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

```
Calendar = CALENDAR(DATE(2020,1,1),DATE(2020,12,31))
```

How can i modify the above DAX with a dynamic "FIRSTDATE" that meets below condition.

1. If the current hour is greater than 16, then FIRSTDATE should be tomorrow else the FIRSTDATE should be today.

Answer (score 0):

Ok got it with `Calendar = CALENDAR(IF(Hour(Now()) >= 16, TODAY() + 1,TODAY()),TODAY() + 2)`